# How can I determine what scope a method is called in?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing something sort of like a kind of benchmarking utility, and I'm curious if there is an easy way to tell from what context a method is being called.  Let me explain by example:

```
module Foo
  my_method
  class Foo
    my_method
    def self.foo
       my_method
    end
    def foo
      my_method
    end
  end
end
Foo::Foo.foo
Foo::Foo.new.foo
```

Ideally, for the above, the "my_method" would print something like the following:

> Called in definition of Module "Foo"
>   Called in definition of Class "Foo"
>   Called during run of class method "foo"
>   Called during run of instance method "foo"

If I could get some kind of reference to the current "scope" or context (or whatever ruby calls it) this would be easy, but I don't know if that's even possible, let alone how to do it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[Kernel#set_trace_func](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) lets you define a tracing procedure (intended for debugging/profiling purposes). For example:

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
  end

  def foo
  end
end

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}

Foo.foo
Foo.new.foo
```

Prints:

```
c-return foo.rb:11 set_trace_func   Kernel
    line foo.rb:13                    
    call foo.rb:2         foo      Foo
  return foo.rb:3         foo      Foo
    line foo.rb:14                    
  c-call foo.rb:14        new    Class
  c-call foo.rb:14 initialize BasicObject
c-return foo.rb:14 initialize BasicObject
c-return foo.rb:14        new    Class
    call foo.rb:5         foo      Foo
  return foo.rb:6         foo      Foo
```

Comment: I saw the set_trace_func, but parsing that out seems heavy-handed.  Is there no $current_scope thing already built in?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Foo::Foo.method(:foo)
Foo::Foo.new.method(:foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside method definition, use `__callee__`. Directly within a module, use `Module.nesting`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

If your *only* requirement is detecting the method inside a module definition, class definition and running method (class or instance method) then you would go with something like the following:

```
def my_method
    if ( a = /^.*?:\d*:in `(.*)'$/.match( caller[0] ) )
        puts ( b = /^<(.*?):(.*?)>$/.match( a[1] ) ) ? 
            "Called in definition of #{b[1].capitalize} \"#{b[2]}\"" :
            "Called during run of #{(self.is_a? Class) ? 'class' : 'instance'} method \"#{a[1]}\""
    end
end
```

**Analysis**

It uses `caller` which contains the stack trace. The first regular expression just parse the syntax of a caller's element which is:

```
[file]:[line]:in `<[type]:[name]>'
```

for module and classes and

```
[file]:[line]:in `[method]'
```

for methods.

Therefore the first regex expressions cuts out the `[file]:[line]:in` part. 
The second one check if there's a `<X:Y>` pattern.

If it does it means that `X` contains either `class` or `module` and can be directly capitalized, `Y` contains the name of the class or module.

Otherwise we have the method name directly and we just have to check whatever it is an *instance* method or an *object* method. For this we just inspect `self`: if it is an instance of a `Class` then we are calling a class method, otherwise we are calling an instance method.

**Test**

On your examples [it gives the following output](http://ideone.com/VThr50):

> Called in definition of Module "Foo"
>   Called in definition of Class "Foo"
>   Called during run of class method "foo"
>   Called during run of instance method "foo"